# Gmail API - How do I see a email opening date?

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I need to use the Google API in order to retrieve the first time an email was marked as view (Specifically, when an email was opened).

I'm using `GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/{id}` requesting only the metadata to get the messages but the response looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "17a05bd8db1609b9",
  "threadId": "17a05bd8db1609b9",
  "labelIds": [
    "CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS",
    "UNREAD",
    "INBOX"
  ],
  "payload": {
    "partId": "",
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "Delivered-To",
        "value": "{EMAIL ADDRESS}"
      },
      {
        "name": "Received",
        "value": "by 2002:a55:c51e:0:b029:e9:12c1:65a9 with SMTP id b30csp1876084egk;        Sun, 13 Jun 2021 07:19:06 -0700 (PDT)"
      },
      {
        "name": "X-Google-Smtp-Source",
        "value": "ABdhPJzPcWJR1zsvAH654luf+agnL6i6CGj8S/jO1MDZVz3yPHcqE7y37chZ7euL02n40t6idUB/"
      },
      {
        "name": "X-Received",
        "value": "by 2002:a9d:62ce:: with SMTP id z14mr10328566otk.255.1623593946243;        Sun, 13 Jun 2021 07:19:06 -0700 (PDT)"
      },
      {
        "name": "ARC-Seal",
        "value": "i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1623593946; cv=none;        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;        b=L8L+Vz979TjsIDtXAyhnPBQUmW8Njjz+DiyScOHFvyHbmOC9sIyaH5AFOafzFou45N         nTtpzyq9pSlZ8VWd6N9N+NYcdldf67A7/FarG9iIs6EvddVYcpbEqdTPOyMt6/mluVQO         utRoX3ma1TFAIyXoQLvxfPZ5QZLZNQFpPwYWGIkB+/8r45OKkqhuWtX8d93InKgpoVIf         NQjaI4Tnr2AJWWJjiALL8bLoCe1QvA3mV+I1sTbGRPZAIPcKfm+nB3smYgkH7f9C+1+8         iXR/45AWh+9Sxd1IFrHHokfTEOQvHEWDXm8BBagCFaRFJv45V+FIyWGJKKpL4UCI0oab         7ZRg=="
      },
      {
        "name": "ARC-Message-Signature",
        "value": "i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;        h=list-unsubscribe-post:list-unsubscribe:mime-version:subject         :message-id:to:reply-to:from:date:dkim-signature:dkim-signature;        bh=3CtcdJdIFbH5c/+55q2hcIqL8foXcatroOK85FVqTxk=;        b=0/F/Qn1AmdXlp7t9Or1qvUB+6xmvr2Ewxm33BtMBo956QCvgQQ5qilxt3ZI1Kqx+YB         zuQZLKRcG7T1kRqvsq3ERdrAqAr6P8+I6j9yWw6XaI7uuU8crVbnEjbkUAheFjmNeXOP         ZcuwtlUPlgDiyOmE6ND2HWLrpUcCKxx/TY17fYkR/H08yr44BqtTXSJVUG12n5Sjb8iA         nnFyJHYBRg2Elw7vMnUl+wiO0k1EH9C7ltwTJCjVsDPe0LcvcjtDcr0R4i24sYbNTDgN         fyOsKMfJnPAE/oLk6iZhd0NvWVkUUvop6b8kdZtLfVH1jLMIYPBOlNjeSct+yfmtrHWt         Vrwg=="
      },
      {
        "name": "ARC-Authentication-Results",
        "value": "i=1; mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@emails.waves-audio.com header.s=gears header.b=AAcEguTx;       dkim=pass header.i=@d.messagegears.io header.s=gears header.b=jvFNHriZ;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 346064636000c23595702-b21164-83d6be2bdc4542f7a574924245020c5e@emails.waves-audio.com designates 135.84.217.27 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=346064636000c23595702-b21164-83d6be2bdc4542f7a574924245020c5e@emails.waves-audio.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Return-Path",
        "value": "\u003c346064636000c23595702-b21164-83d6be2bdc4542f7a574924245020c5e@emails.waves-audio.com\u003e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Received",
        "value": "from mta0201-27.emails.waves-audio.com (mta0201-27.emails.waves-audio.com. [135.84.217.27])        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id t22si9652818otl.163.2021.06.13.07.19.06        for \u003c{EMAIL ADDRESS}\u003e        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);        Sun, 13 Jun 2021 07:19:06 -0700 (PDT)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Received-SPF",
        "value": "pass (google.com: domain of 346064636000c23595702-b21164-83d6be2bdc4542f7a574924245020c5e@emails.waves-audio.com designates 135.84.217.27 as permitted sender) client-ip=135.84.217.27;"
      },
      {
        "name": "Authentication-Results",
        "value": "mx.google.com;       dkim=pass header.i=@emails.waves-audio.com header.s=gears header.b=AAcEguTx;       dkim=pass header.i=@d.messagegears.io header.s=gears header.b=jvFNHriZ;       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 346064636000c23595702-b21164-83d6be2bdc4542f7a574924245020c5e@emails.waves-audio.com designates 135.84.217.27 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=346064636000c23595702-b21164-83d6be2bdc4542f7a574924245020c5e@emails.waves-audio.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "DKIM-Signature",
        "value": "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=gears; d=emails.waves-audio.com; h=Date:From:Reply-To:To:Message-ID:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type: List-Unsubscribe:List-Unsubscribe-Post; i=news@emails.waves-audio.com; bh=3CtcdJdIFbH5c/+55q2hcIqL8foXcatroOK85FVqTxk=; b=AAcEguTxQVhKb8tKVqR1lfLjeU7RxkHAe91vfNVg5UdOTOvGfi+oPi4wnn3dR/XUuFYxu47u9Cfo   g+jeKSONECg68D/xEtQCnf0MfO71lKSLXDghlYhhaAh5Jjd2IH88b+2hM5fBFN7Fz7lDUp1+Bw/0   U9IH4Ei+w7E8RXs/D6E="
      },
      {
        "name": "DKIM-Signature",
        "value": "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=gears; d=d.messagegears.io; h=Date:From:Reply-To:To:Message-ID:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type: List-Unsubscribe:List-Unsubscribe-Post; bh=3CtcdJdIFbH5c/+55q2hcIqL8foXcatroOK85FVqTxk=; b=jvFNHriZksLExFsp7Br0sf598nLFywhbNS7N+70VY0zeKKLxvm0G4EKNUJ3Fe+3a5oWYWa7HBcJS   vq8hAERdI6vQjNNZHYJifHodm4+B04CXCDev9Il3Sx3qB+CYDYymKyeiEycsHWejCdJilo8HN+GE   Cxv+AtCFwq2s68gY/r0="
      },
      {
        "name": "Date",
        "value": "Sun, 13 Jun 2021 10:04:23 -0400 (EDT)"
      },
      {
        "name": "From",
        "value": "Waves Audio \u003cnews@emails.waves-audio.com\u003e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Reply-To",
        "value": "Waves Audio \u003cnews@emails.waves-audio.com\u003e"
      },
      {
        "name": "To",
        "value": "{EMAIL ADDRESS}"
      },
      {
        "name": "Message-ID",
        "value": "\u003c618286522.102678350.1623593063602.JavaMail.cloud@mta0201.messagegears.net\u003e"
      },
      {
        "name": "Subject",
        "value": "ENDS TODAY ⏰ ALL Compressors $29.99"
      },
      {
        "name": "MIME-Version",
        "value": "1.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "multipart/mixed; boundary=\"----=_Part_102678347_1640882403.1623593063602\""
      },
      {
        "name": "X-Original-To",
        "value": "{EMAIL ADDRESS}"
      },
      {
        "name": "List-Unsubscribe",
        "value": "\u003chttp://track.waves-audio.com/list-unsub/uc/2/1cla%3ANDYwNjQ2MzY%3AMDItYjIxMTY0LTgzZDZiZTJiZGM0NTQyZjdhNTc0OTI0MjQ1MDIwYzVl%3AYXJzZXJlZ0BnbWFpbC5jb20%3AMTY1NjkwNQ%3An%3An%3A_8LcuFe86CJ4F5wm08TiWA\u003e, \u003cmailto:unsub-346064636000c23595702-b21164-83d6be2bdc4542f7a574924245020c5e@emails.waves-audio.com\u003e"
      },
      {
        "name": "List-Unsubscribe-Post",
        "value": "List-Unsubscribe=One-Click"
      }
    ]
  },
  "sizeEstimate": 51137,
  "historyId": "6952408",
  "internalDate": "1623593063000"
}
```

And this doesn't show any field like First opened, nor anything similar.

The other approach I was thinking about was checking the history of Labels of the message, if I'm able to retrieve the date at which the UNREAD labelId was added, I would be able to determine the time the email was viewed.

Comment: I don't think there's a direct way to retrieve this date. A possible workaround, though, could be to have a Gmail add-on that uses a [contextual trigger](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/gmail/extending-message-ui#contextual_triggers). You could use that to fire a function when a message is opened and get current date (`new Date()`) and the `messageId` (also keeping track of which messages were previously read). Do you think that would be a valid workaround in your case? I'd consider posting an answer explaining this a bit more.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that it would record the date of the messages that will be opened from now on but I need access to historical data

Comment: Well, history records expire after a short time (commonly after one week or a bit more) (see [Limitations](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync#limitations)), and they don't include a `date` either, so this approach won't be useful for your situation either. So the response to your question would be that you can only retrieve this date for messages opened from now on (using a Gmail add-on). Should I post an answer with this, or you think that would not be useful in any case?

Comment: Yes please go ahead and post a response on how to do this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

In Gmail API, there's no direct way to retrieve the date a certain message was read.

In Gmail itself, there's the option of [requesting a read receipt](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9413651), but this doesn't automatically apply to all emails, and is not available to the API either (consider filing a [feature request in Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191602&template=824107) for this).

Using [users.history](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.history) you can track changes to labels (e.g. `UNREAD`), but the related [History](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.history/list#History) resource does not include information on the dates these label changes occurred, so it would not be useful for your situation either (apart from this, history records expire after a short time, typically around one week or a bit more - see [Limitations](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync#limitations)).

#### Workaround:

Taking all this into account, I think currently the best approach would be to develop a [Workspace Gmail add-on](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/gmail). With this, you can add a [contextual trigger](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/gmail/extending-message-ui#contextual_triggers) that fires a function every time a message is opened (as long as the add-on is being used).

The fired function could then be used to store the current date as well as the `messageId` (for example, using [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service). This way, you could keep track of the dates each message was opened. In this case, the `messageId` (or the `threadId`, for that matter), could be retrieved in your function thanks to [Gmail event object](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#gmail_event_object).

More specifically, you contextual function could be something along the following lines:

```js
function onGmailContextual(e) {
  const messageId = e.gmail.messageId;
  const userProps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  let dateRead;
  const messageProp = userProps.getProperty(messageId);
  if (messageProp) { // If it exists, the message was read before
    dateRead = new Date(JSON.parse(messageProp)); // Retrieve previously store read date
  } else { // If it doesn't exist, the message was not read before (at least while the add-on was open)
    dateRead = new Date(); // Get current date
    userProps.setProperty(messageId, JSON.stringify(dateRead.getTime())); // Store current date as reading date for this message
  }
  // ...
}
```

**Please note that this will only work for messages opened when the add-on is opened, so you cannot use this to retrieve reading dates for old messages**.

#### Further reading:

- [Extending Gmail with Google Workspace add-ons](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/gmail)
- [Build contextual message interfaces](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/gmail/extending-message-ui#accessing_the_add-on_message_ui)
- [Install an unpublished add-on](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons#install_an_unpublished_add-on)